# VBA - How to convert and IEnumerable(Object) to String

Tags: excel, uipath, uipath-studio

I am creating a UI Path bot and using the Excel Read column activity to read contents of a column. I want to use this as text to use somewhere down the line but now the Excel read Column activity outputs an IEnmerable(Object) and I want to pass this to a variable that is a string. So far I am getting an error when I use the following:

```
myTextString = CType(myIEnumerableObject, String)
```

or

```
myTextString = myIEnumerableObject.ToString  (this is simply stored as System.Object)
```

or

```
myTextString = CStr(myIEnumerableObject)
```

What I need is to be able to convert this object to a string, store it in a string variable and be able to re-use it later.

Thanks

Comment: Just a correction for my second alternative attempt myTextString =  
 ```myIEnumerableObject.ToString  (this is simply stored as a string "System.Object")```

Comment: Do you want each cell in the column to be a separate string or the entire column represented as a single string?

Comment: I want the entire column as one big string.

Comment: Can you add 3rd party libraries in UIPath?  If so, try and serialize it using the Newtonsoft.Json library.

Comment: This is NOT VBA code. VB.NET, I'm guessing? Please take care when tagging questinos to use the correct tags, otherwise you won't reach the right people. I'm removing the VBA tags, but you'll want to [edit] to add the correct programming language tags. *READ the tag INFO* before choosing a tag!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `String.Join(<seperator>,myIEnumerableObject)` in an Assign activity, where `<seperator>` specifies the seperator between each element in your `IEnumerable`:

`String.Join(",",myIEnumerableObject)` provides a comma separated string.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data with a `Read Range` activity (specifying range to your desired column or not) , in that way you can store the data in a DataTable variable and access the column directly by name with `mydatatable.Columns.Item("mycolumn")`. It's easier and doesn't require additional coding.